# How to sort by columns with condition in Python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am currently having a problem with pandas sorting. This is what I have: a **table.csv** file with 4 columns

```
     A                       B        C        D
~/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir6        25      Bred     true
~/dir1/dir8/dir12/dir13      45      Alvin    true
~/dir1/dir4/dir5             95      Mary     true
~/dir1/dir2/dir7            125      Bred     false
~/dir1/dir8/dir9/dir11       45      Alvin    true
~/dir1/dir10/dir0            35      Alvin    false
...
```

And I want to sort it with 2 column C and A in the same time. While C is higher priority with ascending order and A is sorted as which string has more "/" (splash) is first and alphabet

This is what I expect from the results:

```
     A                       B        C        D
~/dir1/dir8/dir9/dir11       45      Alvin    true
~/dir1/dir8/dir12/dir13      45      Alvin    true
~/dir1/dir10/dir0            35      Alvin    false
~/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir6        25      Bred     true
~/dir1/dir2/dir7            125      Bred     false
~/dir1/dir4/dir5             95      Mary     true

...
```

I tried

```
df = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
df.sort_values(['C','A'])
```

it only return the alphabet sorted order of *C* column but nothing with the second condition.
Is there any way for me to fulfill the requirement?

Comment: Does `df.loc[df.assign(A=df.A.str.count('/')).sort_values(['C', 'A'], ascending=[1, 0]).index]` work?

Comment: @coldspeed you should post that as an answer, I'd added the `str.count` as a new column in order to do this

Comment: @EdChum I'm a bit hesitant... what I posted gets them 95% of the way there. The only issue is the first and second rows are reversed... I think OP expected a natural sort, but perhaps they aren't particular on that...

Comment: I will try and tell you later @coldspeed

Comment: compile said:TypeError: assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
I am new to Python so i don't know what lead to that problem ! @coldspeed

Comment: All I can assume is you haven't copied the code correctly. It's `A=...`, not `A,...`

Comment: It's my mistake ! i worked perfectly, thanks you !